# Unable to unserialize value in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, error, unserialize, serialize

Whenever I try to access my `local` or `integration` environment I am getting this error.

```
Unable to unserialize value.



Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): Unable to unserialize value.
#0 /Users/suman/the-webster/vendor/magento/module-theme/Controller/Result/MessagePlugin.php(189): Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json->unserialize('Successfully up...')
#1 /Users/suman/the-webster/vendor/magento/module-theme/Controller/Result/MessagePlugin.php(167): Magento\Theme\Controller\Result\MessagePlugin->getCookiesMessages()
#2 /Users/suman/the-webster/vendor/magento/module-theme/Controller/Result/MessagePlugin.php(95): Magento\Theme\Controller\Result\MessagePlugin->getMessages()
#3 /Users/suman/the-webster/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(146): Magento\Theme\Controller\Result\MessagePlugin->afterRenderResult(Object(MGS\Mpanel\Block\Framework\Page\Interceptor), Object(MGS\Mpanel\Block\Framework\Page\Interceptor), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#4 /Users/suman/the-webster/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): MGS\Mpanel\Block\Framework\Page\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#5 /Users/suman/the-webster/generated/code/MGS/Mpanel/Block/Framework/Page/Interceptor.php(156): MGS\Mpanel\Block\Framework\Page\Interceptor->___callPlugins('renderResult', Array, Array)
#6 /Users/suman/the-webster/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(139): MGS\Mpanel\Block\Framework\Page\Interceptor->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#7 /Users/suman/the-webster/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#8 /Users/suman/the-webster/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch()
#9 /Users/suman/the-webster/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
#10 {main}
```

I referred to another stack overflow questions related to `Unable to unserialize value` but was not able to get for `MessagePlugin.php`

What is that error for `MessagePlugin.php` and how can I fix it.

Comment: What is your Php  and Magento version ?

Comment: Follow this link for your issue
https://magecomp.com/blog/solved-unable-to-unserialize-value-magento-2-2/

Comment: Magento version - 2.30, php- 7.1.25

Comment: How can I override  \vendor\magento\framework\Serialize\Serializer\json.php in my module so that instead of reading from Magento\Framework\Serialize\SerializerInterface; it read from my module, I can't change code in vendor

Comment: You can override this class using preference in your module di.xml file.